# Excel VBA - Conditional highlighting based on many criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba-created speadsheet with 4 sets of criteria.  I need to highlight names at the bottom of the sheet based on whether or not they meet all the criteria.

I need the name to highlight if the analyst took 91 minutes or less of total break (B3:F9) each day, 15 minutes or less of tea break (B12:F18), and made at least 3 outbound calls each day (provided the staff time was 8 hours and 58 minutes or more (if it wasn't, the 3 call threshold does not apply)).

So, a function would be something like:

If

TtlB<91 mins & TeaB<15

& If

StfT <8:58:00 ignore ObC

Else If

StfT >8:58:00 & ObC>=3

Highlight (analyst name in A22:A28)

I know it will probably involve a nested loop or two, I just don't know where to get started.  The loop for calculating "Total Minutes Owed" is below which can probably be modified to help me get started with this.

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

j = 3
k = 12
For i = 22 To 28
    Range("B" & i) = "=SUM(G" & j & ",G" & k & ")"
    j = j + 1
    k = k + 1
Next i
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty shure that a much more compact code can be done. But, since nobody answer you in the last four hours, try the following at least as an start.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim oWs As Worksheet
    Dim rAnalysts As Range
    Dim rBreak As Range
    Dim rObC As Range
    Dim rTea As Range
    Dim rST As Range
    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim rIntersection As Range
    Dim rCell As Range


    Set oWs = Worksheets("MyData") 'The worksheet where data resides
    MaxBreakTime = oWs.Cells(1, 7).Value 'The max break time. I set it in cell G1. Change according to your needs

    Set rAnalysts = oWs.Rows("3:9") 'Define the rows for analysts
    Set rBreak = oWs.Range("B:F") 'define the columns where Break data is placed
    '(similarly, set ranges for tea break, etc)

    For Each rRow In rAnalysts.Rows 'for each row in the analyst range
        sAnalystName = oWs.Cells(rRow.Row, 1).Value 'get the name of the analyst
        lBreakTime = 0 'restart this variable to zero
        Set rIntersection = Application.Intersect(rRow, rBreak) ' intersect the row (the analyst) with the columns of the Break range
        If rIntersection Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Ranges do not intersect. Something is radically wrong."
        Else
            For Each rCell In rIntersection.Cells 'id est, friday through thursday
                If rCell.Value > MaxBreakTime Then 'if break was longer that stipulated,....
                    lBreakTime = lBreakTime + rCell.Value - MaxBreakTime 'add the excess to the variable
                End If
            Next
        End If
        'write data somewhere (here, 30 rows down from original Analysts range)
        oWs.Cells(rRow.Row + 30, 1) = sAnalystName
        oWs.Cells(rRow.Row + 30, 2) = lBreakTime

        If lBreakTime > 0 Then
            oWs.Cells(rRow.Row + 30, 2).Font.Color = vbGreen
            oWs.Cells(rRow.Row + 30, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed

        End If
    Next

    'Here something similar for Tea break and Outbounds calls
    'Since output is already writen, you can reuse variables like rIntersection or rCell

End Sub
```